# Uncle's mathematics puzzles after dinner

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

I was at my grandmother's home for a dinner. With my siblings, after the dinner party, watching a prime time show. One of my uncles, who is a mathematics professor, didn't like and asked us to sit down beside him for some puzzles. We solved many formations of Fibonacci and Premium Educational series except one which is posted below:

> 212  224  246  278  310  322

He asked us to tell the previous two and next two numbers of this series. Can someone help me to answer my uncle, who left this as a challenge for us?

Hint 1:

> It is based on the formations of the unique numbers.

Hint 2:

> One of my siblings reminded me that the first number, but not the answer, of this formation series is -7, as told him by Uncle personally.

Hint 3:

> My grandmother's home is at the 5th floor in a 7 story building.

Comment: Is it on purpose that the last number in the series reads 'minus 322' and not 'hypen, space, 322'?

Comment: Nope, the first number is a real negative number '-7', and series is infinite. Updated my first hint to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah, that's my answer out then if it's -322.

Comment: @BreakingMyself the first number is a negative and few more following that but the series showing above in questions only contains a hypen and space not the minus. :)

Comment: Also, what does "formations of the unique numbers" mean? Would it be equivalent to say "no two numbers in the series are the same"?

Comment: Yes, no two signed numbers in the series will be same. But the formulation to obtain each number is same.

Comment: It's very suspicious that all the numbers we know are even (and in fact f(n+1) = f(n)+2 (mod 10) seemingly) but -7 is odd (a debatable point, of course, but certainly "not even".)

Comment: First and last 2 numbers in series might be: (148 180) 212 224 246 278 310 322 (344 376)

Comment: @CR241 I had the same thought but it seems too simple EDIT: can't be because this system does not line up with -7

Comment: I know it's not that simple  but I'm not sure how it line up with -7 (because it's Odd). I don't think so this will format with odd series and negative..

Comment: Is the rule recursive, or can each number be generated irrespective of the others (to an extent)?

Comment: There is a recursive rule to generate each number. @CR241 your 'might be' series is close to the answers but not the correct one.

Comment: That's odd. I actually got (168
200),
212,
224,
246,
278,
310,
322,
(284,
156) I though we used the same method (difference tables?)

Comment: I’m not sure what archaephyrryx meant when they asked “Is the rule recursive?”, but I believe that your response was misleading.  I believe that a recursive rule would mean that it’s easy to compute $U_{n}$ as a function of $U_{n-1}$, and, in fact, that that’s the easiest way to compute $U_{n}$.  But actually, it’s straightforward to compute $U_{n}$ without knowing $U_{n-1}$.  In fact, you *can’t* compute $U_{n}$ as a function of $U_{n-1}$ unless you also know the value of ${n}$ (or $n-1$), as far as I can see. But thanks for a fun, challenging puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The requested numbers are

> $$\mathbf{158,~~ 190},~~ 212,~~ 224,~~ 246,~~ 278,~~ 310,~~ 322,~~ \mathbf{354,~~ 376}$$

The formula for the *n* th Uncle number, $U_n$, is

> $$U_n = 5\times p_n + 2\times n - 19$$
> where $p_n$ is the *n* th prime. 
> The numbers shown in the question are
> $U_{13} = 5\times41 + 2\times13 - 19 = 212$  through 
> $U_{18} = 5\times61 + 2\times18 - 19 = 322$
>
> For completeness, I could explain that
> $U_{1} ~~= 5\times2~ ~+ 2\times1~ ~- 19 = 10 + 2 - 19 = -7$

How did I figure that out?

> - We have a monotonically increasing sequence of integers
>   that begins with an odd number,
>   but it appears to settle into a groove of being all even numbers. 
>   That made me think: that’s one bit off from
>   a monotonically increasing sequence of integers
>   that begins with an even number,
>   but settles into a groove of being all odd numbers.

- Hint #3 mentions some parameters regarding grandmother’s home.

And, having solved the problem and written the solution,
I took another look and noticed that

> - the question body mentions the word “prime”:
>
>   > … watching a **prime** time show.
>
>   Looking at the question’s edit history,
>   I see that Hint #1 originally said, “Is in the first para. 
>   Tricky and you need to look around.” but that was edited out.

Comment: Good work! and this is absolutely correct.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the last two numbers are:

> 344 and 376

And the first two numbers are:

> 158 190

---

Why ?

> Because the difference between the first and second number is 12, now lets add 10 to that and then another 10 now lets subtract 10 and then another 10 till you reach 12 now lets add 10 and another and so on.....

Comment: How do you reconcile that with the given information that the series begins with −7?

Comment: Well I don't know

Comment: @PeregrineRook it starts with -7 but it is not the answer maybe if you continue the series you will get there